# For loops multiple buttons and strings : how to change button text and background and to restore to default settings, if another button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

solution found! see update!

I looked everywhere to find a solution but i couldn't find a satisfied answer to my problem.

I have 100's of buttons with default layout and text. What I'm looking for is a simple,easy method/solution when pressed on button1 to change its text and background and when pressed on button2 to change its own text and background but button1 should go back to its previous/default settings and the other buttons as well.

I have a way to do it but since I have 500 other buttons , it would take me long time to write all of them and I want to keep my code short as well.

Below is the code I'm using now, I hope you guys can be of any help. Thank you!

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

      
            String sometext = "<b>sometext</b>";
            btn1.setText(Html.fromHtml(sometext), Button.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);

            btn2.setText(getString(R.string.todeaulttext));
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);

            btn3.setText(getString(R.string.todefaulttext));
            btn3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String   someothertext= "<b>someothertext</b>";
            btn2.setText(Html.fromHtml(someothertext), Button.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            btn2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);

            btn1.setText(getString(R.string.todeaulttext));
            btn1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
         
            btn3.getResources().getString(R.string.todeaulttext);
            btn3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
```

update: found a solution to my problem testing with nested for loops and it works like a charm.

first for loop = to set the onclickListeners to all buttons.

Second loop = to define text color and background to all buttons.

Third loop = to set the button text(strings) to each button.

Fourth loop with if statement =  to change the text color and background when clicked on a button. Only changes the button text color and background that is being clicked.

Fifth loop inside if statement = to change text(string) of the clicked button only.

I hope this will be of use to others with similar problem writing many buttons with different strings to each button and to set only the button text, text color and background of the clicked button

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < Array.length; i1++) {

```
            buttons[i1] = findViewById(Array[i1]);
            Button btn1 = findViewById(Array[i1]);
            int finalI1 = i1;
            int finalI = i1;

            buttons[i1].setOnClickListener(v16 -> {

                for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
                    buttons[j] = findViewById(Array[j]);
                    Button btn = findViewById(Array[j]);
                    btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);

                    String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.somestrings);

                    for (int k = 0; k < stringArray.length; k++) {
                        buttons[k] = findViewById(Array[k]);
                        Button btn2 = findViewById(Array[k]);
                        btn2.setText(stringArray[k]);
                    }

                    int id = btn1.getId();
                    if (id == Array[finalI1]) {

                        for (int l = 0; l < Array.length; l++) {
                            buttons[l] = findViewById(verbsArray[l]);
                            btn1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                        }

                        if (id == Array[finalI]) {

                            String[] stringArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.someotherstring);
                           
                           btn1.setText(stringArray1[finalI]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be -  if all the buttons are created dynamically hold all of them in a List , assign unique Id to each button (**by using setId/setTag**) programatically. In click listener compare the clicked view ID with List of button IDs and do the required action.

**Below is a working sample code for reference:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() ,View.OnClickListener{

private lateinit var linearLayout: LinearLayout

private val NUM_BUTTONS :Int = 10

private var buttonList = ArrayList<Button>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)

   for( i in 1..NUM_BUTTONS){
       val button = Button(this)
       button.id= i
       button.tag = i
       button.text = "button " + i.toString()
       button.setOnClickListener(this)
       buttonList.add(button)
       linearLayout.addView(button)
   }
}

override fun onClick(view: View) {
    for( button in buttonList){
        if(button.id == view.id){
            button.text = "Clicked Me"
        }else{
            button.text = "Un Click All"
        }
    }
}
```

}

xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thnx I'm not sure how to implement this since I'm not familiar with kotlin. I did find a easier solution and it seems that your provided for loop is shorter for what I found.  switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn:

                    if (btn!= null) {
                        String sometext= "<b>text</b>";
                        btn.setText(Html.fromHtml(sometext), Button.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                        btn.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                    }
                    break;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. It may helpful for someone.

```js
Button[] btns;
int btnClicked = 0;

private void buttonsClickStatus() {
  btns = new Button[]{btn1, btn2, btn3, ......., btn100};
  for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    //default buttons
    btns[i].setText("Not clicked");
    btns[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
    int j = i; 
    btns[i].setOnClickListener(v -> {
      btnClicked = j;
      for(int k = 0; k < buttons.length; ++k) {
        if(btnClicked == k) {
          //After specific button clicked
          btns[k].setText("Clicked "+k);
          btns[k].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
          btns[k].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        } else {
          //Remaining buttons set to default
          btns[k].setText("Not clicked");
          btns[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```