# How to set properties of a Button that was dynamically generated in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating an application that generates `Button`s dynamically based on that database data. Now I have two problems.

1. The dynamically created `Button`s are super generic and they look out of place with the rest of
   my application, so how can I set the text font, background color, size and the padding of
   the dynamically created button?
2. How can I set `ActionEvent` on all the newly created buttons?

Here is the context of what my program is doing: I have a table (named TABLEDETAILS) in my database which has a column named "NoTable" that holds the total number of tables in a restaurant. Now when the *Table Model* button is pressed it generates a button (which represents a table).

```java
public class TableViewController {

    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection Conn = MySqlConnet.ConnectDB();

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private HBox TableLayout = new HBox(10);

    @FXML
    void flowLayout1(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void flowLayout2(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void flowLayout3(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void tableModel(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

        //TODO
        Conn = MySqlConnet.ConnectDB();
        String Sql = "SELECT * FROM tabledetails ";

        //our Collection to hold newly created Buttons
        List<Button> buttonlist = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            pst = Conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int ListOfTable = rs.getInt("NoTable");
                for(int i = 0; i <= ListOfTable; i++) {
                    buttonlist.add(new Button("Table No. " + (int)(i + 1)));
                }
            }

            // remove all Buttons that are currently in the container
            TableLayout.getChildren().clear();
            //then add all Buttons that you just created
            TableLayout.getChildren().addAll(buttonlist);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }
}
```

Screen shots:

[image]

Comment: Use an external CSS file for your styles. That will apply to anything in the scene, so it will apply to the buttons you create. For the event handling, just call `setOnAction(...)` on each button when you create it (you just have to have a local variable for the button).

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your response. I do use external CSS(bootstrap fx to be exactly ) you can see on the screen short all the UI use bootstrap CSS but my dynamic created buttons only user the generic, maybe I don't know proper way of apply CSS on non FXML component, because the rest of the UI I create with scene builder

Answer (score 0):

[For loops multiple buttons and strings : how to change button text and background and to restore to default settings, if another button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475407/for-loops-multiple-buttons-and-strings-how-to-change-button-text-and-backgroun)

```
    Button[] btns;
int btnClicked = 0;

private void buttonsClickStatus() {
  btns = new Button[]{btn1, btn2, btn3, ......., btn100};
  for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    //default buttons
    btns[i].setText("Not clicked");
    btns[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
    int j = i; 
    btns[i].setOnClickListener(v -> {
      btnClicked = j;
      for(int k = 0; k < buttons.length; ++k) {
        if(btnClicked == k) {
          //After specific button clicked
          btns[k].setText("Clicked "+k);
          btns[k].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
          btns[k].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        } else {
          //Remaining buttons set to default
          btns[k].setText("Not clicked");
          btns[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
          btns[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.purple);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You have simply copied the code from another answer. Please learn how this website works. Take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Once you have enough reputation points to post a comment, you can simply post the link to the other question as a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)